# Anybody know of a collection of country outline maps?

Tags: graphics, dictionary

I've been in doubt whether to ask this here, but I don't know where else to go and I think any answers can be useful to other developers...

What I want to do in the community site that I am building is to have a map outline graphic on the header of the user profile. So if the user indicates he is from Brazil, there will an small outline graphic of Brazil next to his avatar. All I want is the graphic, I do not need an interactive map.

For this to work, I figure I could link up the country code to a collection of graphics, each graphic outlining one country. Problem is, is there a resource anywhere with such a repository I can use or buy? I have found some collections that cover part of the world, but I need it to be complete and up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these ..

http://geography.about.com/library/blank/blxindex.htm
http://www.visguy.com/2007/04/23/map-of-world/
http://www.dafont.com/geobats.font
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-vector-world-maps-collection/

and don't forget to check the CIA factbook maps

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/docs/refmaps.html

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [CIA World DataBank II](http://www.evl.uic.edu/pape/data/WDB/), which probably has more detail than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like the GADM-Website: http://gadm.org/